# limit of an absolute value function

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

how would I go about finding the limit of the following absolute value function as it goes to infinity

$\displaystyle\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$

Ive never dealt with multivariable limit functions before?

Comment: "...as it goes to infinity[?]" - as **what** goes to infinity?

Comment: i picked this problem out of a section on metrics, i have found that it is indeed a metric but must now show where it converges to. I was assuming as it went to infinity since I used the isometry of [0.1) but the original problem states that it is in the half openinterval of (0,1]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying. Are you trying to find $\lim_{x,y \to \infty} |1/x - 1/y|$?

Comment: the function looks like d(x,y)=abs{(1/x)-(1/y)}

Comment: I know that (1/x) converges to 0 so (1/x) and (1/y) would both go to 0. but I was told that my assumption that the limit is 0 was incorrect

Comment: @Kathryn, I do not want to offend or be rude. But I recommend to you to be more precise in the wording of its questions. The concept of limit is something well defined in mathematics. And thus the various types of limits have precise and accurate way to evoke them so that makes sense to anyone of the mathematical community.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|=0$$

Justification: I take 
$$\lim_{ x \to\infty} \frac{1}{|x|} =0 \tag{1}$$
 as known. The double limit 
$$\lim_{ (x,y) \to\infty} \frac{1}{|x|} =0 \tag{2} $$
follows from (1): if both $x,y$ are large, then $x$ is large. Similarly to (2), 
$$\lim_{ (x,y) \to\infty} \frac{1}{|y|} =0 \tag{3} $$
Add (2) and (3): 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{y}\right|=0$$
The squeeze  (based on triangle inequality) finishes the proof:
$$0\le \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{y}\right|$$